# How to solve Kafka message producer NoSuchMethodError org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.sslEngineBuilder()

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm trying to run a simple message producer that leverages SSL security to connect with Confluent platform. I am using the `KafkaTemplate` from Spring Kafka for sending the message. However, at the time I call `kafkaTemplate.send()`, I receive the following message:

```
Failed to construct kafka producer
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory.sslEngineBuilder()Lorg/apache/kafka/common/security/ssl/SslEngineBuilder;
```

I am not sure if this issue stems from a missing property in the properties file (e.g. `spring.kafka.properties.*`) , or if the issue is one of dependencies. In my pom.xml file I have the following:

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-avro-serde</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-client-plugins</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.1-ce</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Up to now I have been unable to find why that particular method isn't being found. I suspect I am missing one or more properties, but I'm unsure which one(s).

Within the properties file I have the following values

```
spring.kafka.properties.basic.auth.credentials.source=USER_INFO
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.mechanism=OAUTHBEARER
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.login.callback.handler.class=io.confluent.kafka.clients.plugins.auth.token.TokenUserLoginCallbackHandler
spring.kafka.properties.sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required username=<removed> password=<removed> metadataServerUrls=<removed>
```

Comment: You seem to be missing `org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients` dependency

Comment: I added in that dependency but the error remains. I noticed that in the effective pom, kafka-clients version 2.6.0 is listed in the dependencies, when I don't have the dependency in the pom.xml file. When I do explicitly declare that dependency - even if I put in a different version - effective pom still shows 2.6.0. It also appears in there twice.

Comment: `spring-kafka` will bring it in as a transitive dependency, but that is indeed the dependency that is needed for the class in your error... I'm not exactly sure about the version, though, if that specific method is in 2.6.0. Are you actually using SSL Kafka client properties, though?

Comment: I've updated the post to include the properties. These properties were given by our platform team as the appropriate ones to use for this scenario. We are moving to RBAC.

Comment: I thought there may be something associated with the `ssl.keystore.location` and other properties - removing the values set for those results in a different error fetching activeMetadataServerURLs so it appears that wasn't the issue. Navigating into the `org.apache.kafka.common.security.ssl.SslFactory` class shows that `sslEngineBuilder` method is not there in either version 2.6.0 or the latest 2.8.0. I'm searching to find which version it is in now.

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace? Maybe it's Spring trying to refer to that method

Comment: Another team member provided a sample project they use which has an older version of Spring Boot. I'm able to get the same `NoSuchMethodError` when I go from Spring Boot `2.2.4-RELEASE` (in the sample project) to Spring Boot `2.4.4` (which is what we have in our projects), with no other changes. The older version uses `kafka-clients 2.3.1` and does not exhibit this problem.

Comment: After more digging, I've found Spring Boot 2.4.x = kafka-clients 2.6.0;
Spring Boot 2.3.13.RELEASE = kafka-clients 2.5.1, and that 2.5.1 is the latest version that does not exhibit this behavior (it's the latest in the 2.5.x series).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the research I've done and the help provided here, I've been able to determine the problem is one of compatibility. The Confluent 5.5.1 libraries are incompatible with Spring Boot 2.4.x, because the `kafka-clients 2.6.0` [that is compatible with Spring Boot 2.4.x](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka) is [not compatible with that version of Confluent.](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/versions-interoperability.html)